# Grain, sin, guilt, burned, and freewill offerings. What are the differences?

Tags: torah-study

There are 5 types of offerings I can see in the Torah if not more, if more please point them out as I would like to know the difference between all of them. What are the differences between all these offerings?

1. Grain offering or מִנְחָתָ֞ם
2. Sin offering or חַטָּאתָ֗ם
3. Guilt offering or אֲשָׁמָם֙
4. Burned offering or עֹלָ֣ה
5. Freewill offering or בִנְדָבָ֔ה

Comment: *Nedava* is an *olah* or a *shelamim*. You missed out *todah*.

Comment: Here are some sources on the topic: https://www.aish.com/jl/b/chumash/Chumash-Themes-15-Understanding-Korbanot.html - https://outorah.org/p/37481/ - https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/163455?lang=bi

Comment: please elaborate, are you looking for differences in "why" they're bought? in "how" they're offered? in what was offered? etc...

Comment: see https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Sacrificial_Procedure.1

Comment: A bit of everything. For example, I've discovered so far that a burned offering is burned completely whereas a sin offering is partially cooked and eaten. So that's the outer difference. Now what's the inner difference? Like the spiritual symbol or meaning of it.

Comment: "Freewill offering or בִנְדָבָ֔ה" That's not a kind of offering. The fifth kind is שלמים the peace offering. That was pretty sneaky of you. It was more subtle than usual but I knew a Jesus twist had to be in here somewhere.